# iOS Facebook Custom login not responding on first install

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

For an application I'm developing I am adding the Facebook Login SDK. I have done so before for other apps, but I'm running into some unexpected behaviour in this one. For some reason, the first time the app is started after installation, pressing the (custom) facebook login button fails to open the Safari login screen one would expect to appear. The handler of the login event is never called, preventing me from even displaying an error.

Anyone ever encountered this before?

Code:
AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    // Some other setup code

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app
         openURL:(NSURL *)url
         options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
{
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                                openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                           annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                ];
    handled |= [GIDSignIn.sharedInstance handleURL:url
                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    return  handled;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                               openURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                            annotation:annotation];
    handled |= [GIDSignIn.sharedInstance handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    return  handled;
}
```

Custom Facebook Authenticator:

```
-(void)authenticate: (UIViewController *) viewController onCompletion: (void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *bundle, NSError *error))completion {
    successBundle = [BundleUtils generateBundle:YES];

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: permissions
         fromViewController:viewController
         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        // Never Reached
    }];
}
```

And the relevant info.plist parts (where custom variables are declared in the UserDefined variables for each build configuration in use)

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb${FacebookAppId}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>${FacebookAppId}</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>${FacebookAppName}</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Since I instantiated the FBLoginManager within the authentication function, it would be deallocated while `loginWithPermissions` was still processing. However, this caused a weak reference to the login manager to no longer have a proper value.

Moving `FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];` to the initalizer and storing the login across the session fixes my issues. The fact that this only occured on first setup is probably related to that taking longer to complete, increasing the chance of login being deallocated.